# Removing test data points to improve AUC

Tags: logistic, model-evaluation, auc

Say you are training a logistic regression classifier and you have a training set and a test set and your evaluation metric is test set AUC.  Is is possible to strategically remove datapoints from the test set in order to improve AUC? I'm not saying this is a good idea I am just wondering if it is possible.

I was thinking of something like this.  By definition, AUC is the likelihood that one randomly selected negative example would be ranked lower than one randomly selected positive example.  Therefore, shouldn't the test set AUC necessarily improve if I removed a few of the negative labelled examples (in the test set) that had the highest predicted probability?  If I did this shouldn't it be more likely that a randomly chosen negative example would be ranked lower than a randomly chosen positive example?

Comment: I mean...yes, but you're fooling yourself into thinking the model is better than it is.

Comment: Complete agreement with @DemetriPananos...yes, but it is akin as discounting exam questions you got wrong, simply because you got them way wrong. If anything, getting a prediction way wrong should be a flag to the analyst that the model is confused about something and has room for improvement. When you feed your model a picture of your dog and it comes back with P(cat) = 0.9 or P(Empire State Building) = 0.8, it goofed.